# Load One viewController at a time in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I Have used one third party related to UIPageController in my app. I am displaying categories in my app and I am using the same class to display data. For example, if I'm displaying 5 categories then 5 objects of that viewController are made and 5 objects are in Memory.

Is there anyway to load only one viewController at a time in memory?

Comment: Consider using UICollectionView as an alternative to UIPageViewController, UIPageViewController loads a ViewController which is heavy and most of the time un necessary by loading Cell you will anyway get the benefit of default optimisation and it is light weight as well :) And only one cell will be loaded at any point in time and gets re used on each swipe :)

Answer (score 0):

I can understand that you want to reduce memory usage by achieving this.

`UIPageController` loads all the pages (controllers) when initialized. If you want to do this, you have two options.

- Customize the `UIPageController`
- Use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) control.

`iCarousel` will let you create pages at run time, so you can load one `viewController` at a time. With little customization, you can achieve the required output but definitely, without page control dots.